# Generate Excel File then Input data into Cells

Tags: c#, excel

I want to generate an Excel file with C# for user to put data in, for example in columns [1,2] [3,4] [5,6] then save these data from the user, close the excel file and use the data that was entered for some calculations.

I was able to generate the Excel file but I don't know how to do the rest

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
    Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
    Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

    if (xlApp == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Excel is not installed please intsall it first!");

    }

    xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").Font.Bold = true;
    xlWorksheet.get_Range("D1", "E1").Font.Bold = true;
    xlWorksheet.get_Range("G1", "H1").Font.Bold = true;

    xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "H1").VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
    xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "H1").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;


    xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Crane Locations";
    xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Pick Locations";
    xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 7] = "Set Locations";

    xlWorksheet.Range[xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 2]].Merge();
    xlWorksheet.Range[xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 4], xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 5]].Merge();
    xlWorksheet.Range[xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 7], xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 8]].Merge();


    xlWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\a_hebiba\\Desktop\\Crane.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive);
    xlApp.Visible = true;
    xlApp.UserControl = true;

    xlWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\a_hebiba\\Desktop\\T-Crane.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use C# rather than Excel VBA?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, i know it's hard but it's not my decision :(

Comment: Ok, so you managed to generate the excel. Add workbook.Close() and then the user will be able to open it and enter information.

Comment: this is right but i want the code to be able to read this because when the data it doesn't want to be saved